# INSERT statement that checks if an equivalent row already exists

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL database I have a table `test` that has two columns `foo` and `bar`. I'm trying to write **a single SQL statement** that insert a row only if such a row doesn't already exist. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work if the table is empty:

```
INSERT INTO test (foo, bar) 
SELECT 'foo', 'bar'
FROM test
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
(SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE foo = 'foo' AND bar = 'bar')
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Could you not add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `foo` and `bar` fields?

Comment: @Chief17: Why don't you add that as an answer? it's probably the best.

Comment: I agree that there should be a unique constraint if the columns are unique, but surely using this as a way to prevent an insert in the first instance is not good practise. It will mean an error is thrown when trying to insert `foo, bar`, so any other sql later in the batch will not execute. There are also other considerations such as any client code calling the insert will have to handle an SQL Exception.

Answer (score 2):

The test table is empty, so no record will come in Select. So use `Dual` table with `Select`.

```
    INSERT INTO test (foo, bar) 
    SELECT 'foo', 
           'bar' 
    From DUAL
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   test  
                       WHERE  foo = 'foo' 
                              AND bar = 'bar')
```

`DUAL` is purely for the convenience of people who require that all `SELECT` statements should have `FROM` and possibly other clauses. MySQL may ignore the clauses. MySQL does not require `FROM DUAL` if no tables are referenced.

Comment: Reread the question. This is not the problem. As stated in the question if the table "Test" is empty `SELECT 'Foo', 'bar' FROM Test` will return no results, but foo/bar does not exist in the table so needs to be inserted.

Comment: I hate to be a pedant, but while MySQL does not require a table for a select clause, it does for a where clause so the first query will fail. Since `FROM Dual` is essentially the same as selecting from nothing the second query will fail for the same reason. Example at [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a392f/1)

Comment: @GarethD, behavior of DUAL is different from selecting from nothing. You can verify this, I have written the use of DUAL in post.

Comment: Sorry, you are indeed correct. The error in the first statement was masking the correctness of the second statement.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary for the `EXISTS` clause to reference the table you are selecting from, and since you are only using outer references in the `SELECT` for the insert statement you can use any table to select from, in fact you don't even need to use a concrete table e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Test
SELECT  'foo', 'bar'
FROM    DUAL
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE foo = 'foo' AND bar = 'bar');
```

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c215/1)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
SELECT      'foo'
            , 'bar'
WHERE       1 NOT IN  (
                SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 1
                            THEN 0
                            ELSE 1
                        END
                FROM    test
                WHERE   foo = 'foo'
                        AND bar = 'bar'
            )
```

Note the removal of `LIMIT 1` (I don't think the `LIMIT 1` is hurting, but I don't think it's helping either as the clause was outside the subquery).

Please note the above is tested and works nicely for empty tables.

Also, for the above `IN` is required, not `EXISTS` as `EXISTS` only returns true if a non-null set is returned (or a null-set for `NOT EXISTS`).

Comment: This will not work if the table is empty. Which is what the question is about. This works no better than the INSERT statement in the question (in fact is arguably worse).

Comment: To the contrary, an empty table will return a count of 0.

Comment: Yes, but you are selecting from an empty table. I agree that your count logic works, but you are left with `SELECT 'Foo', 'Bar' FROM EmptyTable WHERE 1 NOT IN (0)` so your `WHERE` Predicate returns true, but this is irrelevant if the table you are selecting from is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can insert a resultset from the same table you're inserting AND checking if the row exists.

Anyway, if not, here is a workaround I guess:

```
INSERT INTO test t1 (foo, bar) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY update t1.foo=t2.foo;
```

EDIT: In your original query I thought you were doing an insert from a select statement. Apparently you just want to insert a given manual tuple, so I changed my suggestion. It should work even if the table is empty.

Answer (score -1):

Could possibly use `REPLACE INTO` which will replace the existing record or create new if none exists. Depends on the specifics of your content though if this approach would work.

Comment: `replace into` would delete any existing row, which is typically not what you want.  Say you have a row creation date, that would be lost.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the specifics if this approach would work.